# Google Cloud Module Project ID

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging, android-manifest, google-cloud-console

I am having a funny co-incidence :P

I have been alotted the project ID : sense-1054

Now I want to use this attribute as a name in my app manifest. And as we know, we can't use the character "-" in it. So it is giving the error:

Error:(39) Tag  attribute name has invalid character '-'.

What should I do?

**[EDIT]**

I am following this tutorial to add a backend to my app related to google cloud messaging api:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints

Scroll down to section 2.4 and read it's last line.

Tried escape sequence but it did not work. Like this:

"sense\-\1054"

Comment: I have not ever used project ID, but project number in my android app. Can you tell me what does that ID use for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I understand. Was confusing package_name with project ID somehow. Corrected it and it works.